# Cannot create 21st query in grafana pie chart graph

Tags: grafana

I am trying to create a piechart graph in grafana 10.
I added 20 queries seperately without problem.
But when i try to add 21 st query it doesnt show it.
Do you know why? Is there a limit?

Comment: Only limit I'm aware of is [26 queries per panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/). And AFAICT, pie chart can show at least 40 segments (if those are returned by a single query).

Comment: Check if you can reproduce the same at play.grafana.com. And if yes - probably it's a bug; consider filing an issue in their repo.